# In Microsoft Azure .net Framework is not recognized in IIS Application Pool

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, windows-server-2012

I am trying to make some ASP.NET website work on Azure.
I have a SQL Server running on the same machine, meaning minimum .net 3.5 is working on it. Also I installed version 4.0 and 4.5 while 4.0 shows up in registry and 4.5 won't show up. Also I can't re-install 4.5 because it is already installed.

In IIS only the .net CLR version shows up, there is no option to make my websites use any other .net Framework version.

When I try to register them using command line : aspnet_regiis.exe -ir 
I get the following error on my 2012 Windows Server:

```
This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administr
ators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Win
dows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.e
xe command line tool.  For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlin
k/?LinkID=216771.
```

also it shows:

```
Finished installting ASP.NET ...
```

But nothing shows up in IIS. What options do I have left? I don't know any.

**Here my selected version in IIS, 4.0**

[image: Selected Version in IIS]

**Here what It shows for the apppools**

[image: Still shows CLR Version in app pool]

Comment: I hope you are using Azure VM. Please confirm IIS and its Application feature is properly installed.

Comment: I am using a windows server 2012 in Azure, yes. IIS and All features installed. tripple checked. Let me update some pictures

Comment: what happening when you hit localhost on your system

Comment: This page can't be displayed. But I have nothing on port 80. When I hit my application on port 81 I see an error from my application about framework version.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45

This has all details. Basically in server you need to use "Add Roles". So check whether 4.5 is enabled in the "Web server (IIS)" role.